# Using Dapper get nested list result

Tags: dapper

I am facing issue for getting students list inside the grade,
I have added minimal code ,Please kindly help me

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CurrentGradeId { get; set; }
    public Grade CurrentGrade{get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

using var connection = _context.CreateConnection()
var students = await connection.QueryAsync<Student, Grade, Student>(sql, 
    (student, grade) =>
    {
        student.CurrentGrade = grade;
        return student;
    }, splitOn: "GradeId");

return students.ToList();
```

How get Students list result in Grade

Comment: I created a github repo that might help you: https://github.com/georgait/DapperRepository

Answer (score 0):

Because one Grade could have many students then you could create this method:

```
public async Task<List<Grade>> ReadGradesAsync<TParameters>(string query, TParameters parameters, CommandType command) 
{
    var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Grade>();
    var result = await connection.QueryAsync<Grade, Person, Grade>(query,
        (grade, student) => 
        {
            if (!lookup.TryGetValue(grade.Id, out var currentGrade))
            {
                currentGrade = grade;
                lookup.Add(grade.Id, currentGrade);
            }
            currentGrade.Students.Add(student);
            return currentGrade;
        }, 
        parameters: parameters,
        commandType: commandType);
      
    return result.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

### Optionally

In order to avoid this boilerplate code you could use the repository pattern with a BaseRepository (or generic) with write and read methods.

To keep this answer on topic i will share only the read method we could use for one-many relationship:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<TEntity>> ReadAsync<TNestedEntity, TParameters>(string query, TParameters parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
{
    var lookup = new Dictionary<int, TEntity>();
    var result = await _connection.QueryAsync<TEntity, TNestedEntity, TEntity>(query,
        (one, many) => Map(one, many, lookup),
        parameters,
        commandType: commandType);

    return result.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

The `Map` method is defined here:

```
internal static class EntitiesMapper
{
    public static TEntity Map<TEntity, TNestedEntity>(TEntity one, TNestedEntity many, IDictionary<int, TEntity> lookup)
    {
        var id = one.GetId();

        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(id, out var currentOne))
        {
            currentOne = one;
            lookup.Add(id, currentOne);
        }

        var collection = GetList<TEntity, TNestedEntity>(one, currentOne);

        collection.AddEntity<TEntity, TNestedEntity>(many);

        return currentOne;
    }

    private static List<TNestedEntity> GetList<TEntity, TNestedEntity>(TEntity entity, TEntity? current)
    {
        var manyProperty = entity!.GetType().GetProperties()
            .FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(ManyRelationshipAttribute), true))!;

        return (List<TNestedEntity>)manyProperty?.GetValue(current)!;
    }
}
```

Inside `Map` method there are a `GetId` and `GetList` methods, these ones use reflection:

```
internal static class ReflectionHelpers
{
    public static int GetId<TEntity>(this TEntity entity)
    {
        var entityType = entity!.GetType();
        var idProperty = entityType.GetProperties()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(PrimaryKeyAttribute), true))!;

        var getId = PropertyHelper.InvokeGet<TEntity, int>(idProperty);
        return getId(entity);
    }

    public static void AddEntity<TEntity, TNestedEntity>(this List<TNestedEntity> collection, TNestedEntity entity)
    {
        var collectionType = collection.GetType();

        var addToCollection = PropertyHelper.InvokeAdd<TEntity, TNestedEntity>(collectionType);
        addToCollection(collection, entity);
    }
}
```

And finally the `PropertyHelper` that uses reflection as well:

```
internal static class PropertyHelper
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Delegate> _cache = new();

    public static Func<TEntity, TResult> InvokeGet<TEntity, TResult>(PropertyInfo property) =>
        (Func<TEntity, TResult>)_cache.GetOrAdd(property.Name, key =>
        {
            var getMethod = property.GetMethod;
            var res = getMethod?.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TEntity, TResult>))!;
            return res;
        });

    public static Action<List<TNestedEntity>, TNestedEntity> InvokeAdd<TEntity, TNestedEntity>(Type type) =>
        (Action<List<TNestedEntity>, TNestedEntity>)_cache.GetOrAdd("Many", key =>
        {
            var addMethod = type.GetMethod("Add")!;

            var delegateType = typeof(Action<List<TNestedEntity>, TNestedEntity>)!;
            var res = addMethod?.CreateDelegate(delegateType)!;
            return (Action<List<TNestedEntity>, TNestedEntity>)res;
        });
}
```

There are also two custom `Attributes`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class ManyRelationshipAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class PrimaryKeyAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Of course in order to use this approach you need to use these attributes in your models.